# Django: checking request user against object.owner

Tags: python, django, validation

I've custom CBV delete view which should check `object`'s owner against `request.user`. 
What is the good practice to do it? 
Currently I've been checking as shown below

```
equal_usernames = some_object.user.username in request.user.username
equal_emails = some_object.user.email in request.user.email
if equal_usernames and equal_emails:
    # some actions
```

Sultan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as:

```
some_object.user == request.user
```

Because Model as `__eq__` defined as such:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self._get_pk_val() == other._get_pk_val()
```

So it's "equal" as long as it's the same model class with the same pk.